# I am experiencing an issue while applying the 'Heading' style to the content pasted from a Word document in CKEditor for Strapi

Tags: ms-word, google-docs, strapi, ckeditor5, html-heading

I want to apply the 'Heading' style of CKEditor to the selected content, which already has inline CSS. I want to retain other formatting for my content. Can anyone help?

'Testing' to be formatted to Heading3
[image: 'Testing' to be formatted to Heading3]

Heading3 style is not getting applied
[image: Heading3 style is not getting applied]

I selected the text and tried to change it to 'Heading3,' but the style did not apply due to inline CSS.